# Problems with including an interface in IronRuby

Tags: c#, ironruby, dynamic-language-runtime

I have an interface which looks something like:

```
interface IMyInterface {
    MyObject DoStuff(MyObject o);
}
```

I want to write the implementation of this interface in IronRuby, and return the object for later use.

But when I try to do something like

```
var code = @"
    class MyInterfaceImpl
        include IMyInterface

        def DoStuff(o)
            # Do some stuff with o
            return o
        end
    end

    MyInterfaceImpl.new";

Ruby.CreateEngine().Execute<IMyInterface>(code);
```

I get an error because it can't be cast to IMyInterface. Am I doing it wrong, or isn't it possible to do what I'm trying to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<s>It isn't possible to implement a CLR interface in IronRuby and pass it back into CLR.  'MyInterfaceImpl' in your example is a Ruby class, not a CLR realization of 'IMyInterface'.</s>

I stand corrected, per Jimmy Schementi's post.

You could however use IronRuby types as dynamic objects inside your .NET code:

```
    var engine = Ruby.CreateRuntime().GetEngine("rb");
    engine.Execute("/*your script goes here*/");

    dynamic rubyScope = engine.Runtime.Globals;
    dynamic myImplInstance = rubyScope.MyInterfaceImpl.@new();

    var input = //.. your parameter
    var myResult = myImplInstance.DoStuff(input );
```

Comment: This is completely incorrect. Implementing interfaces in IronRuby is supported.

Answer (score 4):

What you want to do is possible; IronRuby supports implementing interfaces by mixing the interface into the class.

Running your example I get this exception:

```
Unhandled Exception: System.MemberAccessException: uninitialized constant MyInte
rfaceImpl::IMyInterface
```

This does not mean the object cannot be cast to an `IMyInterface`, it just means the Ruby engine doesn't know what `IMyInterface` is. This is because you must tell IronRuby what assemblies to look up `IMyInterface` in, using `ScriptRuntime.LoadAssembly`. For example, to load the current assembly, you can do this:

```
ruby.Runtime.LoadAssembly(typeof(IMyInterface).Assembly);
```

The following shows you can invoke a Ruby-defined method from C# by invoking methods on an interface:

```
public class MyObject {
}

public interface IMyInterface {
    MyObject DoStuff(MyObject o);
}

public static class Program {
  public static void Main(string[] args) {
    var code = @"
    class MyInterfaceImpl
        include IMyInterface

        def DoStuff(o)
            # Do some stuff with o
            puts o
            return o
        end
    end

    MyInterfaceImpl.new";

    var ruby = IronRuby.Ruby.CreateEngine();
    ruby.Runtime.LoadAssembly(typeof(MyObject).Assembly);
    var obj = ruby.Execute<IMyInterface>(code);
    obj.DoStuff(new MyObject());
  }
}
```

Comment: @Jimmy_Schementi Thanks for the info! I get a different exception when I tried something similar though - I have an interface 'IDummy' in a separate assembly, and I try to 'implement' it in IronRuby.  The exception I get is 'can't convert Concrete into IIntf'.  If I create the object out of IR without casting, and inspect its type, IsAssignableFrom(typeof my interaface) returns false.  What am I doing different?

Comment: Without seeing exactly what you're doing, I'd only be guessing.